# ADO Command object in msaccess

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I don't understand why the following code is failing. Unfortunately to be able to reproduce the problem you must create a valid mysql connection object, or at least another ODBC compatible database.

The following code basically calls a stored procedure like for example `CALL my_procedure(12345);`

The code:

```
' Create ADODB Connection object
Dim oConn As Object
Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Const MYSQL_DRIVER = "{MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}"
Const MYSQL_SERVER = "10.32.27.6"
Const MYSQL_DATABASE = "sales"
Const MYSQL_USER = "root"
Const MYSQL_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx"
oConn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=" & MYSQL_DRIVER & ";Server=" & MYSQL_SERVER & ";Database=" & MYSQL_DATABASE & ";Uid=" & MYSQL_USER & ";Pwd=" & MYSQL_PASSWORD & ";"
oConn.Open


' parameter value
Dim lngAssemblyId As Long
lngAssemblyId = 12345


' Create ADODB.Command
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adInteger = 3

Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    Set .ActiveConnection = oConn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "CALL my_procedure(?)"
    .Prepared = True
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , lngAssemblyId)

End With


' execute command
Call cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing
```

The code above will generate the error "Parameter Type is not supported." at the line `Call cmd.Execute`

I have found a couple of fixes but I don't understand why they work!

**Fix 1**
a) Add a reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"
b) Then Change this part of the code:

```
Dim cmd As Object
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
```

with this code:

```
Dim cmd as New ADODB.Command
```

**Fix 2**
Change the value of adInteger from 3 to 20. The value of 20 represents adBigInteger from the ADODB.DataTypeEnum instead of adInteger. adBigInteger is an 8 byte data type whereas the 'long' datatype in vba and the 'INT' datatype in mysql are both 4 byte data types so this doesn't make sense.

**Fix3**
Change the variable type of lngAssemblyId from Long to Integer. This is strange because 1) I don't need to limit the variable to an Integer in fix 1.
**EDIT**: changing the data type to 'Variant' also works without the drawback of limiting to an integer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you inspect the value of `oConn.Version` when you use `CreateObject` to create it?  If the version isn't "2.8", that might help explain why Solution 1 works.

Answer (score 2):

I've since found a solution to this problem.  Still unsure as to why this works and the original code doesn't though!  Basically I use a subtly different way of binding the parameters:

Rather than this:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput, , lngAssemblyId)
```

use this instead:

```
.Parameters(0).Direction = adParamInput
.Parameters(0).Type = adInteger
.Parameters(0).Value = lngAssemblyId
```